# To replace enter key press event with \n

Tags: html, angular5, enter

**textarea.html**

```
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="array" (keypress)="onKeypress($event)"></textarea>
    <div>
      <p>{{array}}</p>
    </div>
```

**textarea.ts**

```
rray:any;

  constructor() { 
    this.array =["test1", "test2", "test3"];
    // let array2 = ((array).toString()).split("");

    // let array3 = array.join("textarea"); 


  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onKeypress(event){

    if (event.key == "Enter"){
    this.array =  this.array + "\n";
      return false;
    }
  else{
    return true;
  }
  }

}
```

How to print "\n" when enter key is pressed in the textarea using angular 5? The above code does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the error was that I had use "/\n" instead of "\n" as \n is a special character. After doing this it worked

Answer (score 0):

If your code compiles well, then consider adding escape character to show the new line character inline with your textbox area. So instead of "\n" use "\\n".

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enter-key-press-jzrepc) is the working example.